# How to install maven well for neatbeans maven javafx project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, installation, ojdbc

I have a problem when I liked to Run my project:

Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:11.2

Pom.xml:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I thought, the maven not installed well on my Win10.
So what I done:

https://maven.apache.org/install.html -> I download the Binary zip archive ( the first choose )

I unzipped and copy under the C:\   -> C:\apache-maven-3.3.9

I set system variable ( I tried the enviroment too before )

```
M2_HOME = C:\apache-maven-3.3.9 
 and
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin
```

If i open in administrator mode a cmd and I write:

```
echo %M2% -> C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
```

OR

```
echo %M2% -> C:\apache-maven-3.3.9
```

If I write: `mvn --version or maven -version`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mvn --version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>mvn -version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `M2` variable to `PATH` environment variable:

`PATH=%PATH%;%M2%`

Comment: Thanks, this help in maven. I installed this:

` mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

with BUID SUCCESS
but the netbeans again write me:

Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:11.2

Comment: Take a look at that: ``-Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar``. Your xml should be: ```<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
    </dependency>```

Or you should install the ojdbc7.jar again with proper ``artifactId``